# Implicit conversion to pointer type when applying pointer-related operators

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following code:

```
struct X
{
    int x;
};

X xInstance;

class A
{
public:
    operator X*()
    {
        return &xInstance;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    *a = X();   // ok
    a[0] = X(); // ok
//  a->x = 0;   // error
}
```

`A` has an implicit conversion to a pointer type. I attempt to use it in three contexts in which a pointer is required; the two first lines are fine, but attempting to reference a field of `struct X` through `operator->` relying on the implicit conversion to `X*` does not work. Why is that? Conceptually, how is `operator[]` different from `operator->` in this context?

Tested with `g++` 6.3.0 and VC++ 2017.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard section 13.6 lists the "candidate operator functions" that represent the built-in operators for purposes of overload resolution.  When at least one subexpression of an operator @ has class or enum type, the list of functions considered for overload resolution is the union of the non-member lookup of `operator@`, the member lookup of `operator@`, and these candidate operator functions.

For most operators, the candidate operator functions are general enough to represent all the types permitted by the built-in operator.  For example,

> For every cv-qualified or cv-unqualified object type *T*, there exist candidate operator functions of the form

```
T& operator*(T*);
```

> For every cv-qualified or cv-unqualified object type *T* there exist candidate operator functions of the form

```
T& operator[](T*, std::ptrdiff_t);
T& operator[](std::ptrdiff_t, T*);
```

When you write `*a` or `a[0]`, the corresponding candidate operator function wins overload resolution, the subexpressions are converted to the argument types of the candidate operator function, and then the ordinary built-in operator rules apply.

However, the section does not list any candidate operator functions for `operator->`.  So if `a` has class type, the only possible function for `a->x` is the member lookup of `a.operator->()`.  (Non-member lookup does not apply to `operator->`, which must always be a member function.)

Comment: C++14 [over.match.oper]/3.3 also specifically says that for `operator->` 
 (and `operator&`) the built-in candidates set is empty

Comment: @M.M Good catch. I thought that was in there somewhere.

Comment: @aschepler @M.M But what about [over.match.oper]/9? With no viable function (as there are no candidates to begin with), why isn't the built-in operator `->` considered?

Comment: @TSmith It is the built-in operator for that reason, yes. And [expr.ref]/2 says for an arrow operator "the first expression shall be a prvalue having pointer to complete class type". So it's an ill-formed use of the built-in operator.

Comment: @aschepler Ah, I think I was thrown off by the notes (particularly #2 and #3) in [conv.general]. I assumed that implicit conversions always automatically applied wherever they could be used to meet destination type requirements (hence the "implicit"), but I see now that this is only true for _standard_ conversions. (Another example of why these notes should be taken with a grain of salt!)